# Cross-domain iframe to insert cookie

Tags: cookies, iframe, cross-domain

I need to track visitors to websites I own using the same script.

I own both `example.com` and `site.com`

I want to insert `site.com/track.aspx`in `example.com` using an iframe.

`track.aspx` will insert a flash-cookie into the visitor machine and also save some data into a db.

How to do it? Can I achieve the same result without using iframes?

Answer (score 0):

This is a re-redirect mechanism.

`track.aspx` will write a cookie for the `site.com` domain, but you want a cookie which can be read in the example.com domain (I assume)

Create a page in `example.com` which writes cookies and redirects to `site.com`
Create a page in `site.com` which redirects to `example.com`

Have `site.com/FirstPage.aspx` redirect to `example.com/writecookie.aspx?val=abc`
Have `example.com/writecookie.aspx` write the cookie and redirect to `site.com/track.aspx`

Stick `site.com/firstpage.aspx` into your Iframe, and let it do it's re-redirecting.